# Is there any time shift between jmeter and influxdb?

Tags: jmeter, influxdb

Just starting with jmeter and making some experiments I found something that looks kind of odd to me. I connected jmeter with influxdb and measured the avg. time response of one single request in a infinite loop. When I stopped the test I realized that the last time in the results csv created by jmeter is not the same as the one taken by influxdb. Specifically jmeter last measure is 13s higher than the one registered by influxdb. Any ideas on what could be happening?

I've tried to google it but haven't found any documentation or problem related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter sends **aggregated** metrics, to wit it doesn't send each and every [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) but collects the results within some "window", default value is 5 seconds, controllable via [`backend_influxdb.send_interval` JMeter Property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#backend)

And metrics which are being sent are described [here](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html#metrics)

You can try decreasing the 5 seconds window by [amending the aforementioned `backend_influxdb.send_interval` JMeter property](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization) and setting it i.e. to `1000` ms so JMeter would send the data more often but it will create extra overhead so make sure that JMeter has enough headroom to operate and increasing metrics sending rate doesn't affect the overall throughput.